# How to delete the top values before there is a change in the value?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dictionary that has about 5 different dataframes in it and each dataframe has the same columns.

**Sample of one dataframe:**

```
ContextID   BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID  Time_Elapsed    lof
7308924 1.3671875   25  138.33800000000002              -1
7291161 1.3671875   25  138.767                         -1
7291162 1.3671875   25  138.961                         -1
7311376 1.3671875   25  118.28800000000001              -1
7311377 1.3671875   25  118.28800000000001              -1
7308925 1.3671875   25  138.33800000000002              -1
7298660 1.3671875   25  121.25900000000001              -1
7298661 1.3671875   25  121.09500000000001              -1
7313179 1.46484375  25  135.76500000000001               1
7313180 1.46484375  25  135.995                          1
7315853 1.5625  25  139.357                              1
7315654 1.5625  25  137.93                               1
7315653 1.5625  25  137.716                              1
7315321 1.5625  25  137.721                              -1
7315320 1.5625  25  137.57600000000002                   -1
7315281 1.5625  25  137.738                              -1
7314808 1.5625  25  139.19500000000002                   -1
7314809 1.5625  25  139.19500000000002                   -1
```

What I would like is to check from top the `lof` column and the moment the values change from -1 to +1, the -1s must be deleted. Not all the -1s in the `lof` column must be deleted, but just at the top.

The **desired result** based on above dataframe must look like:

```
  ContextID BacksGas_Flow_sccm  StepID  Time_Elapsed    lof
    7313179 1.46484375  25  135.76500000000001               1
    7313180 1.46484375  25  135.995                          1
    7315853 1.5625  25  139.357                              1
    7315654 1.5625  25  137.93                               1
    7315653 1.5625  25  137.716                              1
    7315321 1.5625  25  137.721                              -1
    7315320 1.5625  25  137.57600000000002                   -1
    7315281 1.5625  25  137.738                              -1
    7314808 1.5625  25  139.19500000000002                   -1
    7314809 1.5625  25  139.19500000000002                   -1
```

Notice that only the -1s at the top are deleted and the -1s at the bottom are not.

The same thing must be applied to all the dataframes in the dictionary. I would like to know how can this be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `cumsum()` on `lof==1`:

```
mask = df.lof.eq(1).cumsum()
df[mask.gt(0)]
```

Output:

```
      ContextID    BacksGas_Flow_sccm    StepID    Time_Elapsed    lof
--  -----------  --------------------  --------  --------------  -----
 8  7.31318e+06               1.46484        25         135.765      1
 9  7.31318e+06               1.46484        25         135.995      1
10  7.31585e+06               1.5625         25         139.357      1
11  7.31565e+06               1.5625         25         137.93       1
12  7.31565e+06               1.5625         25         137.716      1
13  7.31532e+06               1.5625         25         137.721     -1
14  7.31532e+06               1.5625         25         137.576     -1
15  7.31528e+06               1.5625         25         137.738     -1
16  7.31481e+06               1.5625         25         139.195     -1
17  7.31481e+06               1.5625         25         139.195     -1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. it works. Is there a way this thing can be applied to a dictionary of dataframes or must this be applied to each df individually?

Comment: not sure what you mean by *applied to a dictionary of dataframes*. You could open a new question and describe your example there.

Comment: Imagine a dictionary where the key is the name of the dataframe and value contains the entire dataframe

Comment: Most likely a `for` loop to apply on each dataframe then.

Comment: just using cummax and eq 1